# How can I reuse coffeescript code?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Coffeescript encapsulate all functions in one file. Which is nice, but brings me a problem:

Let's say I have a coffeescript library, let's say `math.coffee` with the function `gimme_prime(x)` that returns the xth prime number, and you need to use this function in a bunch of files.

So, essentially, how can I reuse coffeescript code?

Comment: This is not CoffeeScript related at all.

Comment: Do you use coffeescript for the server side (node.js) or for client side (browser). This make a huge difference for the question.

Comment: client side, but I don't really like the idea of appending it to window. It is not a global function, I want to reuse it only in other file.

Comment: @Prinzhorn I'm writting coffeescript code and it is not coffeescript related? Or do you mean you can't have a coffeescript program in two files? please explain.

Comment: @fotanus I mean that it all boils down to a JavaScript problem. You can't do a single thing that JavaScript isn't capable of. If you search for JavaScript modularization you'll get much more results.

Comment: You mean: expose certain bits of code like you do when using _the module pattern_?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks, your comment took me to the [right place](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) - It was not the way I was looking for it, but it seems to be the best way to do in javascript. If you answer I can select your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP:

I commented that what he might need was the module pattern, which pointed him towards [this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). I will take a closer look at the article myself, because at first glance it does look promising.

To sort-of restrict access to the functions that the module will expose to only part of the code, you *could* pass objects from those files to the module's IIFE, and wrap all files in an IIFE, too. That way, pass the object back and forth using a global variable (sorry), to which you assign `undefined` as soon as you can. 
Since JS is processed top to bottom, it does matter in what order the files are linked to the page, and where you assign `undefined` to that global variable... but all the same, at some point, for that module to be accessible to other files, unless you're using a lib of sorts, this will require a global variable at some point

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Directly access the global object, e.g. `window.gimme_prime = function() ...`
2. Use some JS toolkit that implements the AMD architecture (see for example the Dojo toolkit).

Comment: I need other option - don't want it global, want it allowed only for some files.

Comment: I think AMD architecture is nearer...